# How to stop Vista from auto changing video resolution?

Tags: windows-vista, display, resolution

I have new Acer Aspire Revo R3600 computer with Vista pre-installed. The computer has NVidia video adapter.

While connecting 17" LCD monitor (LG L1742S) via VGA cable it works fine, and I can change the resolution of the display from max 1280*1024 down to some other value, and after reboot the settings are restored correctly.

But when I'm connecting bigger full HD 1920*1080 display (LG E2250) via VGA cable then every boot I have the same problem:

- I see boot progress window,
- then I see MS logo,
- then I see welcome screen
- then I start to see desktop
- and suddenly monitor switch off and show me the message about unsupported frequency of input signal

As I understand Vista tries to auto-change resolution and sets wrong parameters.

I've tried to boot into low-resolution mode, but I have the same problem: Vista boot-up and suddenly monitor stops working.

**Update:** I've tried to boot into safe mode but computer every time reboots spontaneously, so I can't do anything in safe mode.

I've tried to connect this monitor to notebook with Windows XP and has no problem to work with this display on its native resolution.

**More info:** I've tried the suggestion from [How to change resolution on Vista when it keeps booting to an unsupported resolution?](https://superuser.com/questions/55058/how-to-change-resolution-on-vista-when-it-keeps-booting-to-an-unsupported-resolut/55084#55084) and set low resolution for boot via msconfig utility. What I see after reboot: PC starts with low resolution, I see desktop with all icons, then after 3-5 seconds computer spontaneously changes the resolution to the maximum (1280*1024 @ 17"). What does it can be? NVidia driver?

How can I disable this display resolution auto-changer in Vista? 
Or maybe there is another workaround?

Comment: on a side note, when safe mode does not work it is usually a virus, they mess with it to prevent you from deleting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed all available updates for Vista from Microsoft Update and uninstalled McAffe antivirus which has been installed by default. After that Vista has stopped to automatically change resolution of the display. After that I've installed driver from my display and now it works as expected.

Problem solved, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Vista installs a driver for each vga monitor you plug in, try pluging it and then go to the device manager, uninstall o replace the driver, try first the monitor provided driver and if it didn't came with it, download it from the manufacturer.

Comment: "try plugin it" -- plugin what? 17" or 22"? I can't do anything with 22" because the screen is completely black.

Comment: i see, ok i got an idea, open the resolution configuration screen and then plug your 22" hit print pant(to take a screenshot) and then plug your 17" and then paste the screenshot on paint, it will show you what is windows trying to do, and if it detect it as another monitor, and with the name you can search for drivers.